# java.net.connectException: Connection Refused by apache

Tags: linux, rhel, apache-httpd, tomcat

Recently we have updated our OS from RHEL 6.10 to RHEL 8.4. After the installation of RHEL 8.4, we installed our application which uses Apache internally. Please note that our application is constantly functioning on RHEL 6.10. When we try to start the services in RHEL 8.4, we are getting a “Connection Refused” error. Please find below error,

[image]

Internally, we have redirected the apache port to “8443”. But if we check the Listening port, it still uses 80 port only.

[image]

Moreover, we have added the below command, and we got "Success" as a result of that same. this also didn't help us to solve the error.

> firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8443

Please let us know the workaround solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `httpd` service throws a "connection refused" error because of missing symbolic links. With the help of `ldd` command, I was able to identify the missing links, and adding those symbolic links had made the `httpd` service run.